# How I can fix NewConnectionError in my pip installer?

Tags: installation, pip, package, connection

I have a problem with my pip: any package I want to install returns an error message:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcfa2776760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
```

It isn't problem with my Internet or VPN or DNS, I have checked it.

Before a problem I have tried to install pgadmin and used those commands:

> curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo
> apt-key add sudo sh -c 'echo "deb
> https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs)
> pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
> sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh sudo ufw allow 'Apache' sudo ufw
> enable

And now I can't install anymore else :( Can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to update OpenSSL? Eventually try to update cryptography. It seems to be an old error... https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/main/CHANGELOG.rst#34---2021-02-07

Comment: No, I can't connect anywhere to install anything